# Add Sequence To End of String in Foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Chances are there is a very simple solution to my problem and I'm over looking it. Basically I'm outputting data to a CSV file and trying to make my columns register based off the data in each row using a foreach loop to determine if there is data. **That works!** My issue however is that I want to add a '1' or '2' or '3' etc... depending on what column I'm on in my foreach loop.

```
    foreach ($data as $fields)
    {
        $columnHeadings[] = 'Column #';
    }
```

My problem, is quite literally that simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either count yourself:

```
$num = 1;
foreach ($data as $fields)
{
    $columnHeadings[] = 'Column #' . $num;
    //or
    //$columnHeadings[] = "Column #{$num}";
    $num++;
}
```

Or if `$data` has numeric keys that start with `0` use the `$key => $value` syntax:

```
foreach ($data as $num => $fields)
{
    $columnHeadings[] = 'Column #' . $num + 1;
}
```

See [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for the different ways to use variables in strings.

Comment: I knew it was simple but didn't realize I would be able to throw my variable in a string like that. Lack of PHP knowledge I suppose! Thank you.